# Como implementar classes com método privado?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, interface, método

Estou reescrevendo o código de uma aplicação buscando o melhor uso das interfaces e me deparei com um problema:

Tenho uma classe que precisa ter um método privado e quero criar uma interface para ela, pois tenho outras classes que fazem a mesma função.

Resumindo: como faço criar uma interface que implemente uma classe desta forma:

```
public class Classe implements Interface{

    @Override
    public metodoPublico (){
        ...
    }

    @Override
    private metodoPrivado (){
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Já pensou em utilizar o modificador de acesso "protected" ao invés de "private"? pois quem pode implementar ou ver tais métodos é somente quem a herda.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interfaces não servem para isso. Elas devem declarar contratos que a a API pública da classe deve seguir. Métodos privados são detalhes de implementação e não devem ser exigidos. A classe tem liberdade de atender o que a interface exige do jeito que bem entender, desde que siga o contrato o público. Se vai ter método privado ou não, é problema da classe concreta, ele é privado justamente por isso mesmo. Não faz o menor sentido exigir um método privado.

Se esse método realmente é obrigatório na API pública da classe, faça ele público, se não é, deixe o implementador da classe fazer do jeito que achar melhor.

Dependendo do problema pode ser útil ter uma classe abstrata, mas faria mais sentido se esse método provado for `protected`, e olhe lá, isso quase sempre está errado também. Mas reforço, depende do caso.

Answer (score 1):

Não tem como implementar métodos privados de uma interface, já que uma interface é usada para várias classes igual uma receita, uma API, para cada classe utilizar da sua maneira, como bem entender. Então não faria sentido ter um método privado.

```
public interface Interface {
     void metodoPrivado();
     void metodoPublico();
}
```

Não há distinção, sempre serão públicos.

Comment: Vou dar o +1 mas ficou meio embolada a explicação. Seria melhor dizer que a interface especifica um _contrato_ entre as classes que implementam essa interface e o código que irá fazer uso dessas classes, determinando quais métodos públicos vão estar disponíveis para o código cliente. Por isso só faz sentido a interface declarar métodos públicos.

Comment: Obrigado @Piovezan , então seu comentário fica como complementação da resposta :)